# Сохранение файла

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Сохранил CodeSniffer, но только вопрос. Куда он стал? Откуда можно взять настройки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На том же репозитории, где вы нашли инструкцию по установке в Wiki есть инструкция по использованию: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Usage

Попробуйте запустить `$ phpcs -h`

Ответ на вопрос "как найти папку" можно найти здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30664521/4061802